How to set conditional physical page breaks for an SSRS Report that is formatted for 3 newspaper-style columns per physical page
I am creating a report using SSRS extension in Visual Studio.  I have been attempting to format the report for far too long, and have tried and exhausted every resource I have found in the last week on the topic.  The report has ~200 locations, grouped by 4 regions.  there are approximately 50 in each region.  This report is to be formatted in a Newspaper-style column, with 3 columns per physical page, containing a list of locations.
I am attempting to format it so that each new group starts on a new PHYSICAL page.  When there are multiple columns in the report, each column is counted as page, and therefore, a page break for a new group is only being pushed to the next column.  I am including a diagram that displays the desired behavior of this report.  This is not the exact amount of locations per region.  I have included arbitrary numbers of locations, to demonstrate end of groups in column 1, 2, and 3, each providing a physical page break.
g = group (region)
 
l = location
 
**page 1**
 |c1      |c2      |c3      | 
 |--------|--------|--------|
 |g1.l1   |g1.l6   |        |
 |g1.l2   |g1.l6   |        |
 |g1.l3   |g1.l6   |        |
 |g1.l4   |g1.l6   |        |
 |g1.l5   |g1.l6   |        |
 |g1.l6   |g1.l6   |        |

 group 1 ends on page 1, in column 2.  page break to next physical 
 page.

**page 2**

 |c1      |c2      |c3      | 
 |--------|--------|--------|
 |g2.l1   |g2.l7   | g2.l13 |
 |g2.l2   |g2.l8   |        |
 |g2.l3   |g2.l9   |        |
 |g2.l4   |g2.l10  |        |
 |g2.l5   |g2.l11  |        |
 |g2.l6   |g2.l12  |        |
 
Group 2 ended on page 2, in column 1.  Page break to physical page 3
Group 3 begins on page 3, column 1, row 1.

**Page 3**

 |c1      |  c2    |  c3    | 
 |--------|--------|--------|
 |g3.l1   |g3.l7   |g3.l13  |
 |g3.l2   |g3.l8   |g3.l14  |
 |g3.l3   |g3.l9   |g3.l15  |
 |g3.l4   |g3.l10  |g3.l16  |
 |g3.l5   |g3.l11  |g3.l17  |
 |g3.l6   |g3.l12  |g3.l18  |
 
group 3 did not end on page 3.  spills over to next page, column 1, row 1.

**Page 4**

 |c1      |  c2    |  c3    | 
 |--------|--------|--------|
 |g3.l19  |        |        |
 |g3.l20  |        |        |
 |        |        |        |
 |        |        |        |
 |        |        |        |
 |        |        |        |
 
Group 4 ended on page 4, column 1.  page break to next physical page.

 **Page 5**

 |c1      |  c2    |  c3    | 
 |--------|--------|--------|
 |g4.l1   |g4.l7   |g4.l13  |
 |g4.l2   |g4.l8   |g4.l14  |
 |g4.l3   |g4.l9   |        |
 |g4.l4   |g4.l10  |        |
 |g4.l5   |g4.l11  |        |
 |g4.l6   |g4.l12  |        |



I have tried many methods using tables and lists, single reports, main report with subreport, read endless microsoft documentation, read microsoft q&a boards, read endless microsoft tutorials, youtube tutorials, scoured through stackoverflow (could not find an exact match to the question, with a suitable answer - many did not have in depth explanations of the question, with examples of desired output).  Spent the weekend mapping possible solutions, and using code to help set these page breaks, and still cannot solve the issue.  My sanity is in your hands.

I haven't tried this solution with grouping but try my answer here in the "faking multi-column report using tables" section and add grouping to the tables. I think that should work.
